# Unable to Change NT Service Startup Type

Tags: boot, user-accounts, windows-services

I installed Oracle recently on my Windows 7 laptop, and would like to change the services to startup manually (rather than automatically) because they use something like 1GB of ram. I'm unable to change the Startup type of the service (along with a set of other things).

I understand that it is probably the case that the service doesn't support stopping or pausing, but I can't imagine why Windows  doesn't allow changing Startup type here. I've seen http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itproperf/thread/5680f31f-20bb-4400-92f7-66b052562284 which was interesting, but not helpful. They suggest that Windows protects the DCOM service, and a method of overcoming this protection was suggested. I tried and failed (see the response by `Limited Atonement`).

Please let me know what I should do!

[image: Oracle service won't change]

Comment: Are there other services which depend upon this service, and are also configured to auto-start?

Comment: @DarthAndroid I don't think so. I ran `gsv | % {foreach ($a in $_.dependentservices) { if ($a.name -match 'ora') {echo "got one"} } }` and got no output. Let me know if there's a better way.

Answer (score 1):

All services settings are stored in the registry. You can go ahead and directly change the startup type in the registry.

1. Open registry editor (regedit.exe)
2. Navigate to "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\OracleXETNSListener"
3. Edit the value "Start" and set it to 3. (3 means manual start)
4. Restart the machine.

Note: In case this causes your Oracle applications to break, just change the value to the original value (should be 2 for auto start.)

Comment: This surely isn't the right way to do this. I'm assuming that there's code executing somewhere that's making those controls unavailable, and not only that, but the code is there for a reason! :P

Comment: @LimitedAtonement The correct thing is not to touch the settings. But sometimes to get things done, you may have to use some hacks (and be ready to face the consequences if any)